# CodeIgniter: Image manipulation class doesn't work twice

Tags: codeigniter, image-processing

I'm having trouble trying to resize an image and then create a thumb.

Both functions are working separately but when trying to call them both, only the first call works. No Thumb is created, why ?

Here is my controller:

```
if($this->upload->do_upload()){

                // Si oui, tout va bien

                //Update DB
                $pictureData = $this->upload->data();
                if($pictureData['file_name']!=''){
                    //On resize l'immage
                        //On charge la librarie
                        $this->load->library('thumbs');

                        $this->thumbs->resize($pictureData['full_path'], 300, 600);

                    $News['image']=$pictureData['file_name'];

                    //On crée un Thumbnail:
                        // on envoi le full path
                        if($this->thumbs->create($pictureData['full_path']))

                        // on stock le path recu
                    $News['thumb'] = $pictureData['raw_name'].'_thumb'.$pictureData['file_ext'];
                }
            }
```

And here is the library I've created for both functions:

```
   <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Thumbs
{

    function __construct()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
    }

    public function create($picPath) {

        $CI =& get_instance();

        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $picPath;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['width']     = 100;
        $config['height']   = 100;

        $CI->image_lib->clear();
        $CI->image_lib->initialize($config); 

        if(!$CI->image_lib->resize()){
            $CI->session->set_flashdata('flashError',  $CI->image_lib->display_errors());
            return False;
        }
        $CI->image_lib->clear();
        Return True;

    }

    public function resize($picPath, $x, $y) {

        $CI =& get_instance();

        $config1['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config1['source_image']    = $picPath;
        $config1['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;

        if($x!=0)
            $config1['width']    = $x;

        if($y!=0)
            $config1['height']  = $y;

        $CI->image_lib->clear();
        $CI->image_lib->initialize($config1); 

        if(!$CI->image_lib->resize()){
            $CI->session->set_flashdata('flashError',  $CI->image_lib->display_errors());
            return False;
        }
        $CI->image_lib->clear();
        Return True;
    }
}
```

So if I call only one, it works fine, wether it is the create or resize function. Otherwise, if I try to call them both, only the first function that has been called works.

EDIT: Thanks to fccotech, I made it. here is the solution he came with:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Thumbs
{

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->library('image_lib');
    }

    public function create($picPath, $picName) {

        $config =array();

        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $picPath;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['width']     = 100;
        $config['height']   = 100;
        $config['new_image'] =  $picName;

        // $CI->image_lib->clear();
        $this->CI->image_lib->initialize($config); 

        if(!$this->CI->image_lib->resize()){
            $this->CI->session->set_flashdata('flashError',  $this->CI->image_lib->display_errors());
            return False;
        }
        $this->CI->image_lib->clear();
        Return True;

    }

    public function resize($picPath, $x, $y) {

        $config1 = Array();

        $config1['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config1['source_image']    = $picPath;
        $config1['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;

        if($x!=0)
            $config1['width']    = $x;

        if($y!=0)
            $config1['height']  = $y;

        // $CI->image_lib->clear();
        $this->CI->image_lib->initialize($config1); 

        if(!$this->CI->image_lib->resize()){
            $this->CI->session->set_flashdata('flashError',  $this->CI->image_lib->display_errors());
            $this->CI->image_lib->clear();
            return False;
        }
        $this->CI->image_lib->clear();
        Return True;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After resize add

```
$this->image_lib->clear();
```

So also clear before you do a new  $CI->image_lib->initialize($config);

Comment: so now, the behavior is the following: If I don't try to create a thumb, it resize correctly. If I don't try to resize, a thumbnail is created correctly. If I try both, then no thumbnail is created, and the image is resized at the same dimension as the thumbnail, just like if when asking the create a thumbnail on the already resized image, it doesn't create any new file but instead, overwrite the original with the thumbnail dimensions

Comment: What's funny is, if I invert the lines $this->thumbs->resize($pictureData['full_path'], 300, 600); and if($this->thumbs->create($pictureData['full_path'])) in my controller, then I have the original image as is (non-resized) and my thumbnail is the size of the resized image (and not the thumbnail size)